# Play Framework: why do we return data as JSON and inject it into HTML with JavaScript on the client side?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I'm a bit new to web-development and the Play framework in particular, I just have seen several Play tutorials, and every single tutorial I have seen so far returns a list of models as JSON to the client and then constructs the HTML list out of JSON with JavaScript (translated CoffeeScript) on the client side. Why not just add a code to our HTML view that would do a for-loop and print the list of those models on the server-side? It seems to be a lot easier, intuitive and less error prone.

[Here is one such Play tutorial, the official one from the Play webpage.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLrmnjPQsZc&feature=youtu.be&t=16m5s)

Answer (score 0):

The presentation you're linking describes creating [**Single Page Application (SPA)**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) therefore it fetches data via JSON. Didn't watch it whole just can assume that when author mentions at very beginning that he's gonna to use AngularJS.

Whether using SPA is better or not than common approach depends on many factors, mainly on project specification and can't be answered directly.

The **most** important is that Play allows you to use both of them and doesn't enforce programmers to specific one.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the Scala Templates in PlayFramework for the solution.

the code will be

**In Controller**

```
public static Result orderPage(){
 // put your code here
 List<Order> orderList = new ArrayList<Order>();
 // add your order bean here.  
 return ok(orderList);
}
```

In the app > views create a file orderPage.scala.html and follow the scala template documentation in the following link

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaTemplates

**In orderPage.scala.html**

```
@(orders: List[Order])

<ul>
@for(order <- orders) {
  <li>@order.title</li>
}
</ul>
```

You need to pass the model from controller and receive the model in the html page.